# How to create separated controls for character's armature?

Tags: rigging, armature

Good evening. I want to animate my character and export animation to ue5. The problem is I already have character in ue5 with specific skeleton, so I can't use additional bones in blender. But I still need to find a way to make animations in blender easier and more accurate, like IK, constraints, or something else to prevent this type of situations:[image]

So, I suppose, I need "separated" controls? But how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is, bake animations ("bake action" operation) with visual keying and clear constraints; this should be done by default on an fbx export.  It will write things like your IK constraints to transforms on the bones making up the IK chain.  While it's not generally an issue, you can, if you'd like, target bones in a different armature for these constraints, or for that matter, you can target objects, like empties.

In some cases, you'll find that you'll want to animate bones with a different hierarchy-- perhaps your character is being swung about by their head, and you want to animate with the head bone as the root bone.  In this case, you can use copy transforms constraints, in world space->world space, to give the transforms of the bones of one armature to the bones of another armature that doesn't necessarily share the same hierarchy.  If your head in your Blender animated armature is oriented differently, in its rest pose, than the head in your UE armature, then make a bone in the animated armature that isn't different and parent it to your Blender animated head bone.  Then you can bake these constraints into visual transforms, just as I mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have so much experience with blender animation. Do you mean I can export to UE not only bones but controls too? And can you tell me where I can get more detailed information about it, because I didn't understand half of your sentences(

Comment: "Do you mean I can export to UE not only bones but controls too?"  No, I mean that you can write the effects of your controls into your bones.  "And can you tell me where I can get more detailed information about it"  Try https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/editing.html#bake-action .

Comment: Okay, thank you for answers.